# Laravel 5.5 api unit testing

Tags: laravel, api, unit-testing

I have issue on laravel api unit testing, these are my configs and simple code, but getting "Expected status code 201 but received 500". But with postman everything is ok, why??? please help [config1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjPba.png) [config2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw4Vz.png) [test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q6Yx.png) [controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWjF0.png) [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0Y1P.png)

There is a trait in RegisterController called RegistersUsers and in it is register() method

`Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');`

it calls a register() method and the register method calls registered()

***config 1 - config/database.php***

```
   'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => ':memory:',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

***config 2 - phpunit.xml***

```
   <php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
</php>
```

***test***

```
public function testRegisterSuccessfully()
{
    $register = [
        'name' => 'UserTest',
        'email' => 'user2@test.com',
        'password' => 'testpass',
        'password_confirmation' => 'testpass'
    ];

    $this->json('POST', 'api/register', $register)
        ->assertStatus(201)
        ->assertJsonStructure([
            'token',
            'user' => [
                'id',
                'name',
                'email',
                'created_at',
                'updated_at'
            ]
        ]);
 }
```

***controller method***

```
public function registered(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->guard()->user();
    $success['token'] = $user->createToken('WAI')->accessToken;
    $success['user'] = $user;
    return response()->json($success, 201);
}
```

***result***

```
 developer@developer-v3:/var/www/WAI$ composer test
 > vendor/bin/phpunit
 PHPUnit 6.5.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

  ..F..                                                               5 /   5 (100%)

Time: 3.78 seconds, Memory: 20.00MB

 There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Feature\Auth\RegisterControllerTest::testRegisterSuccessfully
Expected status code 201 but received 500.
Failed asserting that false is true.

/var/www/WAI/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing         /TestResponse.php:78
/var/www/WAI/tests/Feature/Auth/RegisterControllerTest.php:26

FAILURES!
Tests: 5, Assertions: 6, Failures: 1.
Script vendor/bin/phpunit handling the test event returned with error code   1
```

Comment: Have  you debugged what is actually failing? Is it the request body, the URI, is the server itself messing up? etc etc

Comment: yes after $user->createToken() not working

Comment: Okay, so what's happening? Debug it or provide some stack traces. "Its not working" is not very useful.

Comment: What does `createToken` do? Does it call to a server, does it have access to the server? Are you receiving the message on the server?

Comment: it must create a token in db for authentication

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$this->withoutExceptionHandling()` at the top of your test. This will prevent Laravel from resolving the exception to a HTTP status code and offer you a more detailed explanation of the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now can see ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object /var/www/WAI/vendor/laravel/passport/src/ClientRepository.php:81 

and my ClientRepository.php:81 is this function 

` /** * Get the personal access token client for the application.
 * @return \Laravel\Passport\Client */

 public function personalAccessClient() { if (Passport::$personalAccessClient) { return $this->find(Passport::$personalAccessClient); } return PersonalAccessClient::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->client; }` –

Comment: this is 81 line:
return PersonalAccessClient::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->client;

Comment: In my db table oauth_personal_access_clients I have one record with id 1

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the route `'api/register'` is related with the `registered` method.

You are sending a `$register` variable with **user data** but you are not using that.

Try with:

**In Test**

```
public function testRegisterSuccessfully()
{
    $register = [
        'name' => 'UserTest',
        'email' => 'user2@test.com',
        'password' => 'testpass',
        'password_confirmation' => 'testpass'
    ];

    $this->json('POST', 'api/register', $register)
        ->assertStatus(201)
        ->assertJsonStructure([
            'token',
            'user' => [
                'id',
                'name',
                'email',
                'created_at',
                'updated_at'
            ]
        ]);
 }
```

**In Controller**

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::create($request->all());
    $success = $this->registered($user);

    return response()->json($success, 201);
}

public function registered($user)
{
    $success['token'] = $user->createToken('WAI')->accessToken;
    $success['user'] = $user;
    return $success;
}
```

**IMPORTANT**
If you are using Laravel Passport remember to implement `HasApiTokens` trait into the model.

***User Model***

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
```

Comment: No I am using user data. 
There is a trait in RegisterController called RegistersUsers and in it is register() method
`Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');`

Comment: could you put the `api/register` route definition?

Comment: it calls a register() method and the register method calls registered()

Comment: I have a stuff like that, but on  $user->createToken() returns 500 why it can be with postman ok, but with unit testing not ok ? thanks for your response

Comment: please put the `createToken('WAI')` method

Comment: public function createToken($name, array $scopes = [])
       {
            return Container::getInstance()- 
                >make(PersonalAccessTokenFactory::class)->make(
               $this->getKey(), $name, $scopes
             );
       }

Comment: Are you using Laravel Passport?

Answer (score 0):

Is `client` a relationship? If so, you should be calling it with the parenthesis: `client()` - relationships are functions within a model.

Comment: this function is in vendor folder, it is written not by me